# Jade4J for loop unable to evaluate

Tags: javascript, java, web, webserver, pug

I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere, the github for it is not being updated, and I'm about to throw my computer out the window.

I am trying to create a website via java, and am using Jade4J implentation to use Jade.

This is my simple jade file: (indents aren't appearning, they are there)

```
html
title Whatup
-for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    h4 Haithere
```

And all I'm getting is this error:

`unable to evaluate [for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)] - Parsing de.neuland.jade4j.expression.JexlExpressionHandler.evaluateExpression@1:11 parsing error near '... r i = 0; i ...' in test.jade:3`

This works just fine in Node or any other implementation of Jade...

Any ideas... please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a problem for [others as well](https://github.com/perwendel/spark-template-engines/issues/45). You could write a native JavaScript function to create an array based off of a range of values.

```
html
  title Whatup
  -function range(start, end) {
  -    var arr = [];
  -    for (var i = start; i < end; i++) arr.push(i);
  -    return arr;
  -  }
  each i in range(0, 3)
      h4 Haithere
```

Produces:

```
<html>
  <title>Whatup</title>
  <h4>Haithere</h4>
  <h4>Haithere</h4>
  <h4>Haithere</h4>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing pretty much what you said, but did it server sided so I could use it everywhere.